# php array vote by values in array

Tags: php, arrays, sorting

i have an array with many values and i want to get one value is many show of all values. Like this.

my array

```
$allValues = array(0,1,1);         // i want to get 1, because two 1 vs one 0

// other example
$allValue = array(0,0,0,1,1);      // I want to get 0, because three 0 vs two 1

// other example
$allValues = array(0,1);           // I want to get 0, because one 0 vs one 1 is 50:50 but 0 is first value
```

Sorry for my bad english.

Comment: Looking for mode of array - looks like http://stackoverflow.com/a/12036174/2708970.

Comment: Very clearly explained question and requirements but no effort :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
<?php
$allValues = array(0,1,1);   

$result=array_count_values($allValues);   // Count occurrences of everything
arsort($result);                          // Sort descending order
echo key($result);                        // Pick up the value with highest number
?>
```

**Edit:** I've used `key()` because you are interested in knowing the value which has most number of occurrences and not the number itself. If you just need the number you can remove `key()` call.

**[Fiddle](http://codepad.org/AOAxETQW)**

Comment: The shortest and efficient solution. Thumbs up!

Comment: I've a feeling this isn't the shortest. Think it can be shortened further :)

Comment: Nice man, thanks very much @Hanky 웃 Panky.
your answer vote up

Comment: How about the third example? This returns `1` for `array(0, 1)`, not `0` as the OP requested. Otherwise, an ingenious solution.

Comment: I could go ahead and code for that too but you know OP should take the idea and then build upon it for themselves :) Otherwise it becomes a copy-paste job and no learning is inovlved

Comment: I do agree with that, however this is still an incomplete answer and one rather hastily accepted (which, of course, is the OP's fault).

Comment: That's fine I respect your opinion and won't mind if the OP undo's the accept based on that.

Comment: I'm sory, my question is less complete. the values of array will not contains just 0 and 1, i will use that for value of string like this.

$allValues = array('Oke','Not Oke','Not Oke','Maybe','Oke','Oke');

and i want the result is Oke, why Oke? because Oke is most populations of value. This is my reason for acceptable this answer.

Answer (score 3):

try this

```
$allValues = array(0,0,0,1,1); 
$count = array_count_values($allValues);
echo $val = array_search(max($count), $count);
```

Comment: This solution works with all inputs and uses less code than the accepted answer. Well done! You should, however, break down what you did here, it might be immediately obvious to everyone.

Comment: @Antti29 Yes this code works will all the given inputs but it does *not* use less code than the accepted answer. Accepted answer uses 3 function calls and one assignment, this answer uses 3 function calls and 2 assignments. Just because some function calls are nested, doesn't that becomes less code.

Comment: @Hanky웃Panky And I suppose sorting an array (especially if it gets very large) is more efficient than calling `array_search()` and `max()`? You are using one less assignment because you're only echoing the result, which is something this answer could do just as well.

Comment: Yep, do a benchmark and see which answer is faster if you like those numbers. I set up one for you but then i deleted because thats not the question. You can benchmark both answers to see.

Comment: I did just that, and found the results to be, for all intents and purposes, identical (the differences varied and were within the margin of error). Would your code still be as fast if you did get it to return `0` with the third example input?

Answer (score 0):

Works only with 0s and 1s

```
function evaluateArray($array) {
    $zeros = 0;
    $ones  = 0;

    foreach($array as $item) {
        if($item == 0) {
            $zeros++;
        } else {
            $ones++;
        }
    }
    // Change this if you want to return 1 if the result is equal
    // To return ($ones >= $zeros) ? 1 : 0; 
    return ($zeros >= $ones) ? 0 : 1;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
function find_value($array) {
    $zeros = 0;
    $ones = 0;
    for($i = 0; $i < count($array); $i++) {
        ($array[$i] == 0) ? $zeros++ : $ones++;
    }
    if($zeros == $ones) return $array[0];
    return ($zeros > $ones) ? 0 : 1;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use array_count_values — Counts all the values of an array

```
<?php
$array = array(1, "hello", 1, "world", "hello");
print_r(array_count_values($array));
?>
```

**Output**

Array
(
    [1] => 2
    [hello] => 2
    [world] => 1
)