# PHP Calculate Mode Average Containing Negative Values?

Tags: php, average, mode, negative-number

I am trying to find the Mode Average within an array of numbers, which works fine when the array only contains positive values. However, it seems to ignore any negative values in the array and I can't work out why?

```
$test_array = array(3.32,4,-5.51,2,4.44,1,2,3,5,-5.51,-5.51);

$v = array_count_values($test_array); 
arsort($v); 
foreach($v as $k => $v){$mode_avg = $k; break;} 

echo $mode_avg;
```

This outputs "2", when it should output "-5.51" ?

Comment: `break` ????????

Comment: Turn on PHP warnings, and you'll see a lot of this: `Warning: array_count_values(): Can only count STRING and INTEGER values!`

Comment: `3.32` is a `float` not a `integer`, map the elements to `string`.

Comment: Does that mean that I need to convert the array to a list of string values, then convert it back to a number after (for additional math processes) @iainn?

Ignore the "break;" the code is part of a larger function that uses switch and i missed taking that out @RiggsFolly (well spotted)

Comment: Oh....mod averge. Yeah my bad. Didn't read the question properly.

Comment: I converted the string:  //convert to string
$test_array = array_map('strval', $test_array); and then converted it back using: //convert back to float $float  = floatval($mode_avg); Is that the best solution @RiggsFolly ?

Comment: @JamesParry Converting the array to a string and then the result back to a float makes sense to me as a workaround. Ultimately the limitation is that PHP arrays can't use floats as keys, so you'd otherwise need to come up with another data structure if you wanted to do it yourself.

Answer (score 0):

The mode of a numerical set is the number that occurs the most often. You can do this with PHP using code similar to the following:

```
$values = array_count_values($valueArray); 
$mode = array_search(max($values), $values);
```

[Source](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12036174/5283119)

Comment: Did you miss this `Warning: array_count_values(): Can only count STRING and INTEGER values`

Comment: Yup. Could this still not work if all the numbers are multiplied by 100, calculated and divide the end result by 100?